# Calculate $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1^4 + 3^4 + \ldots + (2n-1)^4}{n^5}$

Tags: calculus, limits, proof-verification

Is my solution correct?

By [Faulhaber's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber_formula), $1^4 + 2^4 + \ldots + n^4 = \frac{6n^5+15n^4+10n^3-n}{30} $.

$$\frac{1^4 + 3^4 + \ldots + (2n-1)^4}{n^5} = \frac{1}{n^5} \left[\sum_{k=1}^{2n} k^4 - \sum_{k=1}^{n} (2k)^4 \right] = \frac{1}{n^5} \left[\frac{6\cdot(2n)^5 + o(n^5) - 2^4 \cdot 6 \cdot n^5 - o(n^5)}{30} \right] = \frac{6\cdot2^5 - 2^4 \cdot 6}{30} + o(1) = \frac{16}{5} + o(1)$$

So, $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1^4 + 3^4 + \ldots + (2n-1)^4}{n^5} = 3.2$

Comment: your solution is correct but observe that you can prove it without using the Faulhaber's formula!Try Stolz-Cesaro formula!then you can prove it easily!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using Stolz:

$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1^4 + 3^4 + \ldots + (2n-1)^4}{n^5}=
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(2n+1)^4}{(n+1)^5-n^5}=
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{16n^4+\cdots}{5n^4+\cdots}=\cdots
$$

Answer (score 2):

It is correct, of course, but it would've perhaps been much simpler if one were to just recognize the expression as the **Riemann sum** of $\displaystyle\int_0^1(2x)^4dx$.

Comment: thank you for pointing to such deep connection